# Table Outputs like SPSS plus export to MS Word

Tags: r, spss

Assume the following variable in **R**:

```
test <- c(1,5,4,3,2,3,5,4,2,1,5,1,2,3,4, NA, NA, NA)
```

To get a frequency table, there are several ways of calculation

- "raw" frequencies, this means the frequencies, also including the NAs
- "raw" percentages, same as above, just in percentage
- "valid" frequencies, only those frequencies without NAs
- "valid" percentages, same as above, just as percentage

In SPSS you get this output quite easily with the frequencies-function.

However, in **R**, it's the pain in the ass. As for now, I didn't manage to get a table with the abovementioned values without spending "hours" to build this table output.

Of course, **R** has all the necessary functions for calculating the values, but it's difficult to put them all together in one output, especially if you have NAs, because for the "raw" values you need a row for the NAs, for the "valid" values you do not, but if you put the values together in a matrix or something else, **R** complains that the rows for the raw and the valid scores are not equal.

To make a long story short: is there a possibility to build SPSS-like frequency tables in **R**?

And my second question is, how to export the tables to MS Word.

The problem in **R** is, that the tables use spaces for separating the values. If you copy/paste it into MS Word, you won't be able to build a proper table.

I'm aware that there are some packages, e.g. R2wd (which I didn't even get to work at all) or rtf (which works OK for me), but maybe you now some other possibilities.

EDIT:

The output table of the abovementioned example should look like:

```
Values    raw frequencies    raw percentage    valid freq.   valid percentage
1         3                  16,67             3             20,00
2         3                  16,67             3             20,00
3         3                  16,67             3             20,00
4         3                  16,67             3             20,00
5         3                  16,67             3             20,00
NA        3                  16,67             /             /
```

I have to apologize for that example. I just typed randomly some values between 1 and 5 to get different frequencies. It appears that I unvoluntarily got the same frequency for every value. -.-

Comment: If you have two questions, it is best to simply ask two separate questions. Especially in this case, making the table (in a `data.frame`) and exporting it to Word are two very separate things.

Comment: I agree with that. I just thought it was some kind of related. But you're right. Making a table is different than exporting it to MS Word.

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing a package that, among other things, allows simple table outputs of various (descriptive) statistics. See an example [in this blog post](http://strengejacke.wordpress.com/2014/02/20/no-need-for-spss-beautiful-output-in-r-rstats/) or check the [package at CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sjPlot/index.html).

Code example:

```
require(sjPlot) # load package
# load sample data
data(efc)
# simple frequency table
sjt.frq(efc$e42dep)
```

Result:

[image: table output in RStudio viewer pane]

Comment: This post is rather old. Meanwhile, you find the function in the package [sjmisc](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sjmisc), and it's named [frq()](https://strengejacke.github.io/sjmisc/reference/frq.html). Use `out = "v"` or `out = "b"` to get a HTML-table in the viewer pane or browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use package R2HTML to get SPSS-like output simply. It was very useful for me in same situations.

Answer (score 1):

Altough I don't know exactly how the desired SPSS table should look like, here is my best guess of what you may want to do.

```
freqTable <- function(df, freq.digits=4, perc.digits=2){
  q1 <- table(df, useNA="always")                  # "raw" table
  q2 <- q1/sum(q1)                                 # frequencies
  q3 <- c(table(df, useNA="no"), 'NA'=NA)          # "valid" table; with NA 
  q4 <- q3/sum(q3, na.rm=TRUE)                     # frequencies
  rbind(raq.freq=round(q2, freq.digits), 
        raw.perc=round(q2*100, perc.digits), 
        val.freq=round(q4, freq.digits), 
        val.perc=round(q4*100, perc.digits))
}
freqTable(test)

#                 1       2       3       4       5    <NA>
#  raq.freq  0.1667  0.1667  0.1667  0.1667  0.1667  0.1667
#  raw.perc 16.6700 16.6700 16.6700 16.6700 16.6700 16.6700
#  val.freq  0.2000  0.2000  0.2000  0.2000  0.2000      NA
#  val.perc 20.0000 20.0000 20.0000 20.0000 20.0000      NA
```

For your second question, I suggest using `knitr` to create dynamic documents. If it's a one-time thing, I find that the easiest way is to save a csv-file and import to word from there.

```
write.csv2(freqTable(test), "test_table.csv")
```

Comment: Please see the edit of my original post as to see how the table should look like. In comparison to your output it just has to be transposed. But your example shows exactly the problem. One has to write a somewhat long function. I thought, there might be a more intuiitive way as this is real statistic basics and should be manageable in every statistics software, even in R. Please don't see that as criticism on your solution rather than as criticism on R itself!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there seems to be no R package yet that can generate a nice output like SPSS. Most functions for generating tables seem to define their own special formats, classes, etc. That gets you into trouble if you want to export or work on it in other ways. 
 But from my experience it's possible that R can produce such output. But nobody seems to have worked on it so far and so I started writing my own functions. I'm happy to share the result (work in progress-status, but gets the job done) with you:

The following function returns for all factor variables in a data.frame the frequency or the percentage (calc="perc") for each level of the factor variable "variable".

 The most important thing may be that the output is a simple & user friendly data.frame. So, compared to many other functions, it's no problem to export the results an work with it in any way you want. 

One example: looking at the resulting data.frame with the function "View" and then just copy and paste it to Excel, Word, etc.

I realize that there is much potential for further improvements, i.e. add a possibility for selecting row vs. column percentage calculation, etc. but for now this should be helpful.

```
contitable <- function( survey_data, variable, calc="freq" ){    

  # Check which variables are not given as factor    
  # and exlude them from the given data.frame    
 survey_data_factor_test <- as.logical( sapply( Survey, FUN=is.factor) )    
  survey_data <- subset( survey_data, select=which( survey_data_factor_test ) )    

  # Inform the user about deleted variables    
  # is that proper use of printing to console during a function call??    
  # for now it worksjust fine...    
  flush.console()        
  writeLines( paste( "\n ", sum( !survey_data_factor_test, na.rm=TRUE),
            "non-factor variable(s) were excluded\n" ) )

  variable_levels <- levels(survey_data[ , variable ])    
  variable_levels_length <- length( variable_levels )    

  # Initializing the data.frame which will gather the results    
  result <- data.frame( "Variable", "Levels", t(rep( 1, each=variable_levels_length ) ) )    
  result_column_names <- paste( variable, variable_levels, sep="." )    
  names(result) <- c("Variable", "Levels", result_column_names )    

  for(column in 1:length( names(survey_data) ) ){       

      column_levels_length <- length( levels( survey_data[ , column ] ) )
      result_block <- as.data.frame( rep( names(survey_data)[column], each=column_levels_length ) )
      result_block <- cbind( result_block, as.data.frame( levels( survey_data[,column] ) ) )
      names(result_block) <- c( "Variable", "Levels" )

      results <- table( survey_data[ , column ], survey_data[ , variable ] )

      if( calc=="perc" ){ 
        results <- apply( results, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x){ x/sum(x) }) 
        results <- round( results*100, 1 )
      }

      results <- unclass(results)
      results <- as.data.frame( results )
      names( results ) <- result_column_names
      rownames(results) <- NULL

      result_block <- cbind( result_block, results) 
      result <- rbind( result, result_block ) 
}    
result <- result[-1,]        
return( result )    
}
```